# CodeIgniter - how to load library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I'm using an older version of CodeIgniter when the `application` folder was still in `system/application`. I have pulled the `application` folder out of `system` such that the `application` folder is now at the same level as `system`.

**BEFORE:**

```
/system/application/
```

**NOW:**

```
/application/
/system/
```

Question: how do I now load libraries? In one of my controllers, I tried this:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->library('email', $config);
```

The application dies when it tries to load the email library. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing load i.e.
You need to write `$this->load->library('email', $config);`